# Handling different users in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scene

I am learning Java and JavaFX. I have an application that has some `ComboBox` components that are only visible if logged in as an `admin` My problem is that the application populates the `Combobox` with system variables when it starts,  If a `user` logs in then i get a null pointer and the application doesnt start because the `ComboBox` doesnt exist.. When an `admin` logs in the application starts correctly. Here is how i am trying to get it to work.

```
private void loginpressed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException

{

    if (BCrypt.checkpw(userId.getText() + passwordfield.getText(), passwordhashuser))
        {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LaserControllerUserUI.FXML"));
    Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
    app_stage.show();

        }
    else if (BCrypt.checkpw(userId.getText() + passwordfield.getText(), passwordhashadmin))
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LaserControllerUI.FXML"));
        Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
        app_stage.show();
    } 
    else{
        errorMessage.setText("Login Incorrect!");
        System.out.print("false");}
}
```

So i have two seperate FXML depending on who logs in.  How do i handle this?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, this is not a good idea what you are doing. That it also some very intense casting.... I mean really intense it's quite disturbing, maybe even a little offensive!

Comment: Yes i figured it wasnt correct.  How would you handle it?

Comment: Don't use underscores either in Java. Follow the conventions. These conventions are sometimes relied on in many different frameworks.

Comment: Understood and corrected.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should avoid making your application in a way in which it will need administrative privileges, if it does need these privileges you will need to give this feedback to the user, or enforce this condition, you can google how to do this such as in this link for Microsoft: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431742.aspx. Note that you can have access to the current user through the System properties in Java, and you can also save properties based on a user as well, if that helps.

That casting your doing completely unnecessary. I would look up some GUI tutorials on MVC for Java if I was you. Once you learn this pattern you will have a light bulb moment and everything will just make sense. There are alterations of this pattern you should learn the main ones.

Not following any GUI patterns will cause you immense pain and complications. I would estimate over 100,000 questions on SO would not exist if people knew this pattern. This includes your question. GUI and functionality should be completely separated. Your question would simply be: how do I get a list of all Users, which would be a duplicate and not need to be asked.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer.  MVC is new to me so i will go and read that. With regard the users.  I wasnt referring to Windows users, I have a login page on my application and two pre-configured users who should see different screens after they input credentials.  My application requires no Administrator privileges to run.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one FXML Document. If they have pretty much the same components, I would set the locations and visibility of the components after a user logs in. What is set to visible should depend on the users account type.